# Loop condition in bash

Tags: bash, loops, infinite-loop

In bash script, below while loop is supposed to print 1 to 4 number.

But this one is resulting as an infinite loop.

```
COUNT=1

while [ $COUNT < 5 ];
do
  echo $COUNT
  COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
done
```

Is there any fault in condition or syntax ? (I think so...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-lt` instead of `<`:

```
COUNT=1; while [ $COUNT -lt 5 ]; do   echo $COUNT;   COUNT=$(($COUNT+1)); done
1
2
3
4
```

BASH syntax with `[` doesn't recognize `>, <, <=, >=` etc operators. Check `man test`.

Even better is to use arithmetic processing in `(( and ))`:

```
COUNT=1; while (( COUNT < 5 )); do echo $COUNT; ((COUNT++)); done
```

OR using `for loop`:

```
for (( COUNT=1; COUNT<5; COUNT++ )); do echo $COUNT; done
```

Comment: accepted...Yes this will solve problem, what is wrong in mine ?

Comment: Answer is accepted. more details will be appreciated :)

Comment: I guess I have already provided my recommendation i.e. use the last for loop and see how clean your code is. BASH has changed a lot so better adapt to modern syntax and ditch `[` command wherever possible.